# E-learning for Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, new-users

Some of the frequent discussion and debate on the site revolves around:

- New users find it hard to get started
- New users don't have access to basic features and make do with what they can (post comments as answers)
- New users find it difficult to get used to community norms and etiquette
- Experienced users get frustrated with repeatedly having to solve the same basic problems with poor quality
- Both sides see the other as a problem as it can be difficult to see the other point of view

One way of easing tensions may be to create some kind of e-learning about the basics of the site and how to ask a good quality question. The completion of this could grant a small amount of rep (say, 50) which would allow access to some of the features since it would be proven that an understanding of how things work has been reached. Hopefully new users would feel more confident and quality would be improved.

I'm not saying it would solve all problems, but it may help some. Is it worth a try?

Comment: So basically like the [tour], just more content and a reputation award instead of a badge? It's seems to go a bit against the idea of reputation being a measure of how much stuff you have contributed to the community if you can get it for reading an extended tour.

Comment: @Secespitus if you read the tour before asking, that's the greatest contribution you can do as a ... dedicated asker.

Comment: @Secespitus I was thinking there would be some assessment involved, rather than only reading.

Comment: Question is, would people who already aren't making use of what the site offers when they come in as newbies use this? It seems lots of people are in too great a hurry to take the existing orientation, can't imagine why something else would get their attentiion enough to hold them back from wanting to ask that burning question that brought them here, to begin with...

Comment: @CindyMeister The coercive power of magic internet points...

Comment: It's hard to understand why the existing info doesn't get across, but maybe something gets lost in reading. In a video you could see a real human explaining the guidelines, and, just as important, how it's not personal. Humor and direct but tactful messaging that fall flat in writing can be effective in a video. I've seen it work wonders. Email me and I'll provide an example.

Comment: I think the point that James is trying to make is that it should be neither like the tour nor like a video. Not a **passive** experience, but an interactive one with performance checks to help the user internalize the concepts. To go above a manual, never mind the medium.

Comment: I'm in favor of this, but the rep gain doesn't seem like a good idea. Especially if it's 50. This could let spammers easily gain access to comments, and the comment moderation tools are so awful it's hardly worth calling tools. We'd have to significantly improve that system before I'd feel comfortable with 50.

Comment: As a "getting started" I think it's only going to help if people can't opt-out... As something to point people to who are having problems, as an alternative to "read the site guidelines", yes, it could help.

Comment: Meh, no opt-out might be awkward. I'd love to see something similar to [WP:TWA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:The_Wikipedia_Adventure) (but obviously made for SE). That one specifically also does a really good job at demonstrating the expected interaction tone.

Comment: You might want to flesh out and propose a concept. E-learning is very, very broad, and you could say the tour and help section is a form of e-learning (a particularly passive one, but it's digital and it's a learning resource). Personally, I think there might be a truly helpful variant, and I think we might be able to compromise on the opt-out, perhaps making it required after someone has posted X consecutive poorly received questions. Imo badges are the proper system to reward this, depending on the effort a bronze or silver one might be appropriate.

Comment: This is another take on, "Require new users to take a quiz before they can ask their question".  While I'd *dearly* love a way to better convey familiarize them with our standards...I'm not sure there's any way we can reliably do that.  There needs to be some investment on the asker's end to *want* to understand; not sure what we can do to engender that want.

Comment: I like the idea of such a tool. But, instead of using points as reward, SO could offer it as a way to get out of the question ban (once). It's not as good as preventing bad questions in the first pace, but may be helpful in salvaging them.

Comment: Even if this isn't about a video, maybe a video would be a good idea. It's a low-investment experiment. What if you take the same thing you've been trying to say different ways in text for years, a smiling human face says it instead, and it works? What if it works some of the time? Sometimes you don't know what works without trying. It gives a way to express the message while also having a little fun with users' misconceptions and frustrations.

Comment: FWIW, there's an *online course* on how to use Stack Overflow/Exchange on Pluralsight: [Using Stack Overflow and Other Stack Exchange Sites](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/using-stackoverflow-stackexchange-sites)

Comment: It is [also on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLTbIqtg8Gb0pdq7RBIxAdtw7HGb1jimPg). But it needs some kind of index or TOC to be really effective (70 lessons! - no number between 49 and 50).

Answer (score 7):

The limitations I see with this are twofold:

First, there's nothing really stopping anyone from gaming a system like this.  Because such a system can't scale to include humans offering responses or approvals (and I shudder at the thought of sending submissions like this through a new queue), at some point someone's going to have the system figured out, get an easy 50 rep, and still ask poor questions.

Second, this overlooks the real heart of the issue.  All we want are clear questions, and for the OP to be able to find an answer to their question if it exists already.

The former is only something that lies with the OP and how well they communicate with us.  We can edit and spruce up some language, but if all *we* get is some code and some requirements, then there's not much we can extrapolate from that.

The latter is something only Stack Overflow devs can put effort into fixing.  Allowing a user to find a duplicate question with significantly greater accuracy would allow an asker to accomplish their objective here - to get their question answered.

The norms we have aren't that arcane.  All we want are clear and on-topic questions, and topicality is spelled out in [the Help Center](https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  If no one chooses to read that, then we're throwing money into the void to solve what is turning into the most complex problem on the Internet.

Comment: "at some point someone's going to have the system figured out, get an easy 50 rep," and can [comment everywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: How would the game work? It could only be obtained once. And I would hope the assessment was sufficiently robust as to prevent automated success. I suppose someone may create sock-puppet accounts, gain the 50 rep and then award it to a main account as a bounty, but that should be easy to detect and preventable in any case by putting rep bar on awarding bounties.